# Clear form using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a checkbox to clear a form but I do not want the reset to clear the checkbox itself. The code I am using is as follows:

```
<input name="no_cage" id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="this.form.reset();">
```

When I click on the checkbox it clears the form fine but unfortunately, also clear itself too.

The checkbox also updates a db with a 1 if checked or a 0 if unchecked. So I need it within the form and it needs to be able to toggle between checked and unchecked.

Comment: Use the checkbox out of the form tag

Comment: How would you reset the form again if the checkbox stayed checked?

Comment: The checkbox also updates a db with a 1 if checked or a 0 if unchecked. So I need it within the form and it needs to be able to toggle between checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

Create a javascript function to reset the form and then check the checkbox again to true.

**Using JQuery**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', '#no_cage', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("client").reset();
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
</script>
<form id="client">
    <input type="text">
    <input id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1"> CLEAR
</form>
```

**Using Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearform(){
    if (document.getElementById("no_cage").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("client").reset();
        document.getElementById("no_cage").checked = true;
    }
}
</script>
<form id="client">
    <input type="text">
    <input id="no_cage" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:clearform();"> CLEAR
</form>
```

OR,
keep the checkbox out of the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearform(){
    document.getElementById("client").reset();
}
</script>
<form id="client">
    <input type="text">
</form>
<input id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="javascript:clearform();"> CLEAR
```

Comment: Your first option partly works but does not allow me to uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: The first option works great. I have a further issue where there is also a select input that pulls data from a DB and includes the selected option. The clear checkbox does not removed the selected option. Do I need to post this as a new issue or is it ok to include it here?

Comment: Post new issue and leave link here, for my instance

Comment: And if this helped, please tick it as correct answer

Comment: Thanks Prakash - just posted new question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want it this way, but I change the code that if checkbox is checked than clear form else it won't. Here the code

```
<form id ="myForm" name = "test">
<input type ="text"/>
<input type ="text"/>
<input type ="text"/>
<input type ="text"/>
</form>


<input name="no_cage" id="no_cage" type="checkbox"  onclick="resetForm()">

<script type="text/javascript">

function resetForm()

{
if (document.getElementById("no_cage").checked == true)

{ 

document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="checkbox"  id="box"onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">reset
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
document.getElementById("box").checked = true;
}</script>
```

hope it helps