# Resetting a select input that has a selected option

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which was supplied via another question that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569651/clear-form-using-a-checkbox/39570198#39569869).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', '#no_cage', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("client").reset();
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
</script>
<form id="client">
    <input type="text">
    <input id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1"> CLEAR
</form>
```

I now want to include a select input as per the following:

```
<select name="cage_labor">
   <option value="Select Labor" <?php if ($cage_labor=="Select Labor") echo "selected"; ?>>Select Labor</option>
   <option value="Non Union"  <?php if ($cage_labor=="Non Union") echo "selected"; ?>>Non Union</option>
   <option value="Union"  <?php if ($cage_labor=="Union") echo "selected"; ?>>Union</option>
</select>
```

I want the reset form checkbox to ignore the selected option and default to "Select Labor". Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got confused on what you actually want.

**If you want to ignore the attribute `selected` and set to defaultValue**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', '#no_cage', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("client").reset();
        this.checked = true;
        $("#cage_labor").prop("selectedIndex",0);
    }
});
</script>
<form id="client">
    <input type="text">
    <select name="cage_labor" id="cage_labor">
        <option value="Select Labor">Select Labor</option>
        <option value="Non Union" selected>Non Union</option>
        <option value="Union">Union</option>
    </select>
    <input id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1"> CLEAR
</form>
```

**If you want to ignore the whole select input**:

When a form resets, it resets everything there is. Like you have done `this.checked = true` to reassign the value to checkbox; to make it look like reset button ignored the select, all you have to do is, assign value of that select input to a variable and reassign value to select input once the form resetting is complete. Something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', '#no_cage', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        var value = $("#cage_labor").prop("selectedIndex");
        document.getElementById("client").reset();
        this.checked = true;
        $("#cage_labor").prop("selectedIndex",value);
    }
});
</script>
<form id="client">
    <input type="text">
    <select name="cage_labor" id="cage_labor">
        <option value="Select Labor">Select Labor</option>
        <option value="Non Union" selected>Non Union</option>
        <option value="Union">Union</option>
    </select>
    <input id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1"> CLEAR
</form>
```